# $n$ dimension integrals involving one dimension Dirac delta functions

Tags: integration, functions

I want to calculate an integral 
$$\iint_D f(x,y)\delta(g(x,y))\,dx\,dy$$
or simply 
$$\iint_D \delta(g(x,y))\,dx\,dy$$

$\iint_D \,dx\,dy$ is the area of $D$, and$\iint_D \delta(g(x,y))\,dx\,dy$ seems like we pick out the area of curve $g(x,y)=0$? or something else like it ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you meant, then yes, it is something like that. Have a look at
[this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Properties_in_n_dimensions) of Wikipedia's Dirac delta function page for a formal definition.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
First integrate respect, for example $y$, for $x$ fixed:
$$
\int\delta\pars{{\rm g}\pars{x,y}}\,\dd y
=
\int\sum_{n}
{\delta\pars{y - \fermi_{n}\pars{x}}
 \over \verts{\left.\partiald{{\rm g}\pars{x,y}}{y}\right\vert_{y = y_{n}}}}\,\dd y
\quad\mbox{where}\quad{\rm g}\pars{x,\fermi_{n}\pars{x}} = 0
$$
The result is a function of $x$. Then, integrate over $x$ ( No problem !!! ).

For example:
\begin{align}
&\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\delta\pars{x^{2} - y^{2}}\,\dd y\,\dd x
=
\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\bracks{{\delta\pars{y + \verts{x}} \over 2\verts{x}} + {\delta\pars{y - \verts{x}} \over 2\verts{x}}}\,\dd y\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{1}^{2}\int_{1}^{2}{\delta\pars{y - \verts{x}} \over 2\verts{x}}\,\dd y\,\dd x
=
{1 \over 2}\int_{1}^{2}
{\Theta\pars{\verts{x} - 1}\Theta\pars{2 - \verts{x}}  \over \verts{x}}\,\dd x
=
{1 \over 2}\int_{1}^{2}\,{\dd x \over x} = \half\,\ln\pars{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If the argument of the delta function is a vector valued function, e.g.

$$ I = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \delta\left[ \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x}) \right] f(\mathbf{x}), $$

then you must calculate the determinant $|\det\nabla \mathbf{G}| = |\det\partial_i G_j|$, as

$$I = \frac{f(\mathbf{x_0})}{\left|(\det\nabla\mathbf{G})|_{\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x_0}} \right|} $$